# Java ; can not convert String Matrix to Double Matrix : Errorjava.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, matrix

I've tried to solve this issue 3 days ago but nothing happens. I hope you can find a solution:

i'm making an application to read a txt file of numbers after that, i captured the data into a String Matrix and to operate them i need to convert it to a double matrix. but an error appear:

### Errorjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0,95768412 0,770070937"

. ive tried to replace the comma (.) for (.) but nothin happen.

Here a thumbnail of the file info:
*0,620966467    0,397670717

0,144506398 0,86070719

0,344924707 0,49886148

0,568299164 0,407224505

0,55644466  0,580297755

0,940100947 0,920269925

0,45667026  0,253952562

0,046970841 0,04214613

0,548769197 0,114155205

0,220420195 0,035404045

0,804653981 0,371228693

0,688345818 0,575313752

0,54377148  0,891464466*

i post the code for you can see the program.

```
try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\numerosAleatorios.txt"));

        //String matriz[][] = new String[99][1];
        double matriz[][] = new double[99][2];
        int numlineas = 0;
        while (((Linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {

            String a[] = Linea.split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

                matriz[numlineas][i] = Double.parseDouble(a[i]);

            }

            numlineas++;
        }

        //double matrizDoble[][]= new double [99][1];
        System.out.println("MATRIZ");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");

        for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.length; filas++) {
            for (int colum = 0; colum < matriz[filas].length; colum++) {
                //matrizDoble[filas][colum]= Double.valueOf(matriz[filas][colum]).doubleValue();

                System.out.print(matriz[filas][colum] + "\n");

            }  
        }



            System.out.println("\n Numero de parejas: "+numlineas);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error"+ex);
    }
```

Thanks for answer.!

Comment: Decimal numbers must be using `.`, not `,`, so you have to replace comma with `.`

Comment: Still wrong, i replaced all  to ( . ) intead commas( , ), but the error keep.

Comment: Try outputting to the standard output to see if the numbers are indeed properly parsed.

Comment: i added a "e.printStackTrace();" to see more detail. In the tray i get this:
`java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0.620966467 0.397670717"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at series.series.leerTxt(series.java:26)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Split your String by white space:

```
String a[] = Linea.split("\\s+");
```

2) Replace ","  with "." :

```
matriz[numlineas][i] = Double.parseDouble(a[i].replace(",", "."));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code with replacing ',' with '.' and it works fine for me.

[image]

[image]

```
String Linea;
try {

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src\\numerosAleatorios.txt"));

    // String matriz[][] = new String[99][1];
    double matriz[][] = new double[99][2];
    int numlineas = 0;
    while (((Linea = br.readLine()) != null)) {

        String a[] = Linea.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

            matriz[numlineas][i] = Double.parseDouble(a[i]);

        }

        numlineas++;
    }

    // double matrizDoble[][]= new double [99][1];
    System.out.println("MATRIZ");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");

    for (int filas = 0; filas < matriz.length; filas++) {
        for (int colum = 0; colum < matriz[filas].length; colum++) {

            System.out.print(matriz[filas][colum] + "\n");

        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n Numero de parejas: " + numlineas);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Error" + ex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using String.split() with a "space"; however, your stacktrace shows a "tab" between the numbers. No space is found in the string, so it doesn't split. It then tries to parse both numbers in the string at once: "0.620966467   0.397670717" which fails.